# App installed but didn't launch automatically

Tags: android, eclipse

I run my App, it uninstalls the previous app & places the newly build app in my device, Which causes me to go to the menu, then find the app, then tap it to run... 
This problem is found in only 1 project of eclipse.

Console output  :

```
[2014-07-11 20:15:26 - MyApp] Android Launch!
[2014-07-11 20:15:26 - MyApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-11 20:15:26 - MyApp] Performing sync
[2014-07-11 20:15:28 - MyApp] Uploading MyApp.apk onto device '1C9E_9E18_MicromaxA111'
[2014-07-11 20:15:31 - MyApp] Installing MyApp.apk...
[2014-07-11 20:15:40 - MyApp] Success!
[2014-07-11 20:15:41 - MyApp] \MyApp\bin\MyApp.apk installed on device
[2014-07-11 20:15:41 - MyApp] Done!
```

My manifest

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>
```

My phone android version is 4.1.2 so I included `android:targetSdkVersion="16"` which doesnt solve the issue, Also I have restarted Eclipse & my device also.

Can Anyone explain me why this is happening ?

**UPDATE** Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"/>

<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

        android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
android:value="com.example.MainActivity" />
<meta-data
android:name="android.app.searchable"
android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If you click the down arrow next to the run button, then click "run configurations", do you have any configurations defined? If so, make sure that the "Launch Default Activity" option is selected.

Comment: Thanks @Tanis.7x It worked as you say , thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the down arrow next to the run button, then select "Run Configurations".

[image]

In the dialog, make sure that "Launch Default Activity" is selected.

[image]